# how to automate some actions on Windows form Application?

Tags: c#, forms, automated-tests

I have a working windows form desktop application that I have created. The application is doing some jobs on monthly basis. Every month I need to run the application and there is a connect button. which I click and then it loads up in a dropdown menu some lists and I choose one of them and click another button to do the job. So what I would like to do is automate this process and just let the application to do this job for me every month as a scheduled. I do not want to go inside to code and make it a console application and run the console application from tasks schedule. I am just wondering is there any way that I can create another small application and define the steps to take (similar Macros or test projects(codedUI Test)) to do the job for me?

Answer (score 1):

May be you just need something like AutoHotkey? http://www.autohotkey.com/

It's already 'another small application' and you can 'define steps to take' with it :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) - Python tool/library for automating GUI applications. It's very easy to use and perfect for tasks you described:

```
click(Button("Connect"))
click(ComboBox("Drop Down Menu Name"), "Option 1")
press(ENTER)
```

You can save the commands in a text file with the .at extension and run it easily from command line whenever required:

```
> Automa.exe your_script.at
```

*Disclaimer: I'm one of Automa's developers.*